# Matlab set all values of containers.Map

Tags: matlab, dictionary

I have a Map named myMap in Matlab with `string,int` pairs.
I want to perform an operation(say add 2 to all values) on all values. How can I do it ?
I tried

```
 myMap(keys(myMap)) = myMap(keys(myMap)) + 2
```

But it gives error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myMap=containers.Map(myMap.keys,cell2mat(myMap.values)+2)
```